# Как сделать dropdown в JSF editable?

Tags: java, java-ee, jsf, primefaces, dropdown

Необходимо сделать поле ввода в виде выпадающего меню с возможностью редактирования. Но кажется в JSF это не поддерживается. Есть Richfaces или Primefaces. http://www.primefaces.org/primeui/#dropdown

Библиотеку Primefaces primefaces-5.3.jar загрузил и поместил ее в папку lib в эклипсе. При запуске меню Dropdown появляется но но при попытки ракрыть меню ничего не происходит. xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" в станице JSF добавил.Написал следующий код:

```
     <p:selectOneMenu editable="true" value="bean.name"  >
        <f:selectItem itemValue="Cream Latte" itemLabel="Coffee3" />
        <f:selectItem itemValue="Extreme Mocha" itemLabel="Coffee3 - Extreme Mocha" />
        <f:selectItem itemValue="Buena Vista" itemLabel="Coffee3 - Buena Vista" />
     </p:selectOneMenu>
```

Появляется только:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом при нажатии на стрелочку не показываются элементы меню. Как сделать чтобы они показывались? Спасибо.

Comment: Компонент расположен внутри `h:form`? В консоли смотрели ошибки JS? В генерируемом html-коде ваши элементы есть?

Comment: да внутри h:form. В консоле ошибок нет. В генерируемом html-коде выдается: <div id="j_idt24:j_idt29:j_idt30" class="ui-selectonemenu ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all"><div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"><input id="j_idt24:j_idt29:j_idt30_focus" name="j_idt24:j_idt29:j_idt30_focus" type="text" autocomplete="off" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" /></div><div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"><select id="j_idt24:j_idt29:j_idt30_input" name="j_idt24:j_idt29:j_idt30_input" tabindex="-1"><option value="Cream Latte">Coffee3</option><option value="Extrem.......

Comment: Application Server Wildfly

Comment: в web.xml появилось  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
  </listener>    с предупреждением listener-class references to non-existent class "com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener"  Но возможно оно и было.

Comment: Не работало потому что была добавлена библиотека jquery-2.2.3.min.js. После удаления работает.